# How can I access a model attribute from a queryset with a template tag?

Tags: django-templates, django-views, django-queryset

I've added the following model's objects to my view using the get_context_data() method.

**models.py:**

```
class Icon(models.Model):
    icon_name       = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='iconset')
    icon            = models.ImageField(upload_to='machine_icon/', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.icon_name)
```

**views.py**

```
class MachineSorter(DetailView):
    model = MachineCount
    template_name = 'brands/machines.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MachineSorter, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['icon'] = Icon.objects.all()
        return context
```

I can loop through the icons easily and display them like this:

```
    {% for obj in icon %}
    <img src="{{ obj.icon.url }}"> 
    {% endfor %}
```

But I *DO NOT* want to loop through them, I just want to access an individual icon image where needed, such as:

```
<img src="{{ icon.name.url }}">
```

...or something to that effect. When it comes to using additional context in views, the examples I see all use loops.  What am I missing here?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A queryset is a *collection* of icons, it thus contains *zero*, one or *more* items. Therefore it does not make much sense to obtain such attribute. What should happen in case the collection is empty? Or contains multiple items?

Comment: Okay, thank you.  However perhaps I didn't ask clearly.  What I am asking is whether it's possible to call (display) one of my icons from the queryset using the django template tag language, directly, and not with a loop as shown.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried to retrieve just what you need with a query?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects